# how to configure js-beautify to preserve long string multi-lines alignment

Tags: javascript, js-beautify

I installed successfully [js-beautify](https://github.com/einars/js-beautify) and I am using it from within xemacs on Debian Linux. By default, when formatting a string concatenated line, I get the following:

```
   var astr = "head of string" + avarstring + ...
```

I cannot find how to configure the auto-formatting of a string to respect
the following indentations:

```
   var astr = "head of string" 
              + avarstring
              + ...
```

I do not really care about having the `+` sign at the end of each line or 
at the beginning, but I really need, for readability and maintenance activities,
to have each separated substring to be on a single line.

Question:

1. Which option should I use to configure this behavior?
2. Where should I position the configuration JSON file to load this configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found:

A new option was added a few month ago (but does not seem to be released in the `npm package` downloaded by default).

- Option is present in the github: motzke/js-beautify
- Option is named: `wrap_before_operator`
- The most simple configuration directory location is in the npm
  directories (in my case): `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/js-beautify/js/config/defaults.json`

Comment: Hey Alain. I can't find any trace of "wrap_before_operator" in their git repository. Do you know the status of this, or have you found another solution to this problem (to preserve string multi-lines)?

Comment: Sorry, it has been over a year I got around this problem.  No update for now. Best luck.

Comment: @corgrath - An `operator_position` option has been added.  Does that do wha you want?